Pytest and PyCharm: how to get <Click to see difference> always?
There is a difference in the assert output of Pytest in PyCharm depending on if function with assert in the same file or in the another file.
Let's consider an example.
tmp.py:
from utils.tmp_1 import assert_in_another_file


def test_assert():
    d1 = {
        1: 2,
        3: 4
    }
    d2 = {
        3: 4,
        5: 6
    }
    assert_in_the_same_file(d1, d2)
    # assert_in_another_file(d1, d2)


def assert_in_the_same_file(d1, d2):
    assert d1 == d2

tmp_1.py:
def assert_in_another_file(d1, d2):
    assert d1 == d2

If I run with assert_in_the_same_file:
def test_assert():
    d1 = {
        1: 2,
        3: 4
    }
    d2 = {
        3: 4,
        5: 6
    }
    assert_in_the_same_file(d1, d2)

Output:
Expected :{3: 4, 5: 6}
Actual   :{1: 2, 3: 4}
<Click to see difference>

If I run with assert_in_another_file:
def test_assert():
    d1 = {
        1: 2,
        3: 4
    }
    d2 = {
        3: 4,
        5: 6
    }
    assert_in_another_file(d1, d2)

Output:
>       assert d1 == d2
E       AssertionError

No Click to see difference, No Actual, Expected
Is it Pytest or Pycharm issue? How to fix it and get "Click to see difference" always?

This would be a PyCharm issue, but I cannot reproduce it with a current version of PyCharm.

I checked with
PyCharm 2023.3.5 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-233.15026.15, built on March 21, 2024
The issue is in place.
Do you use the same version?

I can reproduce that if I use this tmp_1.py name.
I you rename the file to the discoverable by pytest name like test_tmp_1.py you will see normal assertion.
This is because nice assertion output is thanks to pytest assertion introspection.
You can read more in
https://pybites.blogspot.com/2011/07/behind-scenes-of-pytests-new-assertion.html
If you do not want to rename the file to make it discoverable by pytest you can add register_assert_rewrite
pytest.register_assert_rewrite("tmp_1")

And see nice pytest-style assertions from it.
